# Update SQL table with list of dictionaries

Tags: python, mysql, sql

How to proper use dictionaries in SQL queries? Should I predefine SQL variables to prevent SQL injection?
E.g. I've got an error in Python while trying update table with dictionary, but query works perfect in pure SQL with predefined variables and values.

`_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Incorrect datetime value: '1' for column 'colF' at row 1`

My dict

```
     {'ID': 1, 'colA': 'valA1', 'colB': 'valB1', 'colC': 'valC1', 
        'colD': 'valD1', 'colE': 'valE1', 'colF': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 23, 0, 0), 
'colG': datetime.datetime(2018, 
        7, 11, 0, 0), 'colH': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 0, 0)}
```

SQL statement

```sql
UPDATE table1
    SET 
    colA = CASE \
    WHEN %(valA1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valA1)s 
    END,\
    colB = CASE \
    WHEN %(valB1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valB1)s 
    END,\
    colC = CASE \
    WHEN %(valC1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valC1)s 
    END,\
    colD = CASE \
    WHEN %(valD1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valD1)s 
    END,\
    colE = CASE \
    WHEN %(valE1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valE1)s 
    END,\
    colF = CASE\
    WHEN  %(valF)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valF)s
    END,\
    colG = CASE\
    WHEN  %(valF1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valF1)s 
    END,\
    colH = CASE\
    WHEN  %(valH1)s IS NOT NULL THEN %(valH1)s
    END\
    WHERE %(ID)s = Id """
```

When I format a query string

```sql
 colF1 = CASE  
    WHEN  2018-07-11 00:00:00 IS NOT NULL THEN 2018-07-11 00:00:00 
    END,
    colH1 = CASE
    WHEN  2018-09-01 00:00:00 IS NOT NULL THEN 2018-09-01 00:00:00
    END 
    WHERE  Id = 1
```

And another issue `when value is not null`. Syntax is wrong, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues arise with your attempted parameterized query:

1. As described in [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) docs, column or table identifiers cannot be used in parameter placeholders. Such placeholders are only used for literal values. Also, consider the triple quote strings for multiple lines to avoid `\` line breaks:

   ```
   sql = """UPDATE table1
            SET 
              colA = CASE 
                        WHEN colA IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN %(valA1)s 
                     END,
            ...
         """

   cur.execute(sql, mydict)
   con.commit()
   ```
2. To use the named placeholder approach, dictionary keys must match placeholder names. Currently, you need to reverse most of your key/value order in dictionary which you correctly do only for `ID`. However, as mentioned in #1 above, remove any column identifiers:

   ```
   {'ID': 1, 'valA1': 'data value', 'valB1': 'data value', 'valC1': 'data value', ... }
   ```
3. Datetimes in most databases including MySQL must take the string form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. MySQL engine cannot execute Python's `datetime()` objects. However, some DBI-APIs may be able to convert this object type.

   ```
   {'valF': '2017-12-23 00:00:00', 
    'valG': '2018-07-11 00:00:00', 
    'valH': '2018-09-01 00:00:00'}
   ```

Comment: I didn't know that order is important when I use named placeholders. I've already tried this  `stmt = "UPDATE table SET col1 = %(value)s WHERE id =%(id)s"
params = [dict({'id': k, 'value': v}) for k,v in dict.items()] for updating 1 table and 1 column. # [{'id': '1', 'values': 'a1b1c1'}, {'id': '2', 'values': 'a2b2c2'}, {'id': '3', 'values': 'a3b3c3'}]
cur.executemany(stmt, params)` and it worked. Strange. I thought if I have `key:value` pairs I cane safely correspond them to SQL columns name.

Comment: If I change order as you say e.g. `SET @ID = %(ID)s, @colA = %(valA1)s;\
                               SELECT concat_ws(@ID, @ColA);` and then `cur.executemany(sql_stmt, mydict)`. After fetchall() output is `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.` Why is so?

Comment: Order is not important (since dict keys are unique) but keys must align. By *order* I mean swap them so named params are the keys which your posted dict has *cols* as keys. And once again, do not attempt to parameterize table/column names. It is unclear what you are attempting with `@` which denotes a MySQL parameter.

Comment: Nope, my dict is ok. I've found an issue. Changed `SET CASE` to simple `ifnull()`.